# C program to find all the prime factors. example: 24 will have 2 2 2 3 as answer

Tags: c, recursion

C program to find all the prime factors. example: 24 will have 2 2 2 3 as answer.I have used recursion.help me out please.the output for 12 is coming:2,3,4,6 which is not as expected

```
#include <stdio.h>

int primeno(int i)
{
    int j,afg;
    for(j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if((i%j)==0)
            afg=0;
    }
    if(j==i)
        afg=1;
    return afg;
}
void prime(int num)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(((primeno(i))==1)&&((num%i)==0))
            printf("%d\n",i);
        else if((!primeno(i))&&((num%i)==0))
            prime(i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("enter the number whose prime factors are to be found\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    prime(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could format your code properly in order to make it more readable ?

Comment: Unless I misread, the algorithm you're using is called **trial division**. You can google that. Also, you should take a look at C code style guidelines. Your code is not clear (your lack of whitespace in particular) and not helping you find the problem. Readable code is easier to analyze and debug.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (primeno implicitly declared, main's return type is implicit). If you fix all the compiler errors and warnings, we can try to build and run and debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `int primeno` function will always return `1`. At the end of the `for` loop in this function, `j` is *always* going to equal `i`. What you want to do instead is set `afg=1` above the loop, and remove the `if` statement afterwards.

Comment: yeah..i added a break statement in the for loop.works fine now

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
void printAllPrimeFactor(int n)
{
    // Print the number of 2s that divide n
    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", 2);
        n = n/2;
    }

    // n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip one element (Note i = i +2)
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
    {
        // While i divides n, print i and divide n
        while (n%i == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    // This condition is to handle the case whien n is a prime number
    // greater than 2
    if (n > 2)
        printf ("%d ", n);
}


int main()
{
    int n = 24;
    printAllPrimeFactor(n);
    return 0;
}
```

**OR** use this function:

```
void printAllPrimeFactors(long number) {
         long temp = number; 
         for (int i = 2; i <= temp; i++) 
         { 
             if (temp % i == 0) 
             { 
                    printf("%d ",i); // prime factor 
                    temp /= i;
                    i--;
             }
         }
 }
```

Comment: you can change `for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)` to `for (int i = 3; n != 1; i += 2)`.